# How do I add facebook Icon for Angular Material2?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

The default list of Angular Material Icon does not contain the social media icons like facebook, twitter, linkedin, etc.

Any idea how do I achieve this ?

```
<mat-icon>facebook</mat-icon>

<mat-icon>youtube</mat-icon>
```

Comment: This may help you.It is an angular package for font awesome. I think it evens has animations, albeit basic.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome

Answer (score 8):

Actually, with almost 3 years progress, I can say that facebook mat-icon was added:

```
 <mat-icon>facebook</mat-icon>
```

Let's wait for 3 years more and maybe other ones will be added too